# Angular Js run After Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs

How can i run ajax inside angular ajax?

I have angular like this

```
Index.html

MyApp.controller('MainController',
    function($scope, $http, $location , $compile) {
        $scope.content_middle = 'Welcome';            

        $scope.goto = function(path){
            $http.get( path ).success(function(response) {
                $scope.content_middle = $compile(response)
            });
        }
    }
);
```

And then some anchor

```
<a href="" ng-click="goto('user.html')">User</a>
```

This will load user.html with ajax.

```
User.html
<table class="table table-hover"  ng-controller="UserController">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>No</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody ng-repeat="user in users">
    <tr>
        <td>{{user.no}}</td>
        <td>{{user.name}}</td>
        <td>{{user.username}}</td>
        <td>{{user.date}}</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
// this will load data.txt with ajax angular
MyApp.controller('UserController',
    function($scope, $http, $location) {
        $http.get('data.txt').success( function(response) {
            $scope.users = response; 
        });
    }
);
</script>
```

Is that possible?
Because i want to use it for dynamic call.
I have use this kind of ways in AdvAjax and its magnificent.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="" ng-click="goto('user.html')">User</a>
```

Loading another HTML using `ajax` is not good choice.

For basic routing angular has [$routeProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) service which required [ngRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) modules.

For advance feature, [AngularUI Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) is angular module for routing. It has `directive` named `ui-view` and `service` named `$state` for routing from one page to another. It provides **Nested States & Views** and **Multiple & Named Views**.

Answer (score 0):

better off using ... [AngularUI Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) - The de-facto solution to flexible routing with nested views